# Mockito ArgumentCapture to doesn't recognise multiple generic types

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to use Mockito's `ArgumentCapture` to retrieve a generic argument used however in my method the same base type is used but with different generic arguments twice.

To simplify the example I've written a test different from my code but with the same problem:

```
    @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<String>> stringl;
    @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<Boolean>> booleanl;

    @Before
    public void setup()  
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);      
    } //setup

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Boolean> booleanList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        foo.doSomething(stringList);
        foo.doSomething(booleanList);

        verify(foo).doSomething(stringl.capture());
        verify(foo).doSomething(booleanl.capture());
    } //test

    private static class Foo
    {
        public <T> void doSomething(List<T> list){}
    }
```

Executing the test produces the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
foo.doSomething(<Capturing argument>);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at test(Test.java:19)
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at test(Test.java:21)
```

To see what was happening I added `times(2)` to the verify methods and then inspected the argument captures.  Both picked up the second invocation meaning I could never capture the first argument of type `List<String>`.

Is there a way to get `ArgumentCapture` to recognize different generic types for the same base type i.e. differentiate between `List<Boolean>` and `List<String>`?

Cheers,
Alexei Blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using the existing `ArgumentCaptor` class. Due to type-erasure this information is lost. I suggest you use a single captor and get the argument passed in all invocations. You can then verify that it was called the first time with `List<String>` and the second time with `List<Boolean>`. Of course you would do this by verifying the contents of the Lists.

Comment: Thanks @John, I feel very stupid for not seeing captor.getAllValues() before hand.  I've changed my test to verify(mock, times(2)).doSomething() and then I get the mocks from the list passed back and verify the contents as suggested :) Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

My changes to correct this were:

```
@Captor private ArgumentCaptor<ArrayList<?>> aList;

@Before
public void setup()  
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);      
} //setup

@Test
public void test()
{
    Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);

    String testString = "Hello Test";
    Boolean testBoolean = true;

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringList.add(testString);

    List<Boolean> booleanList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    booleanList = testBoolean;

    foo.doSomething(stringList);
    foo.doSomething(booleanList);

    //verify to capture and assertion that it happened twice
    verify(foo, times(2)).doSomething(aList.capture());

    //Get all captured values from the verified invocation
    List<ArrayList<?>> args aList.getAllValues();

    //verify first list, should be String
    assertEquals("TestString assertion wrong", testString, args.get(0).get(0));

    //verify second list, should be Boolean
    assertEquals("TestBoolean assertion wrong", testBoolean, args.get(1).get(0));
} //test

private static class Foo
{
    public <T> void doSomething(List<T> list){}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternativ would be an injected `ArgumentCaptor`

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<List<Person>> argumentCaptor;
```

http://blog.jdriven.com/2012/10/mockito-using-argumentcaptor-for-generic-typed-collections/

Answer (score -4):

For me i am trying to throw the same error massage two times.

If you are trying to verify the same massage then you have to use "times" method of `import static org.mockito.Mockito.times`;

```
verify(anyFakeObject,times(num)).method(parmeter);
```

where numb is the count for  same massage.